# Save and update on same button?

Tags: angular

How can I call save and submit from the same button?

```html
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-brand"
        [disabled]="!frmAgrTemp.valid"  (click)="SubmitInfo()">
        Save
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-brand"
        [disabled]="!frmAgrTemp.valid"  (click)="UpdateInfo()">
       Update
    </button>
```

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

in general you can has a variable that indicate when is a new reg or not, e.g.

```
newReg:boolean=true

//at very first, e.g. in ngOnInit if params get a parameter you can make
this.newReg=false
```

Then you has two options:

1.-two buttons with a *ngIf to show one or another

```
<button type="submit" *ngIf="newReg" ...>Save</button>
<button type="submit" *ngIf="!newReg" ...>Update</button>
```

2.-An unique button that change the caption and unique function that save or update the reg

```
<button type="submit" (click)="Submit()" >{{newReg?'Save':'Update'}}</button>

Submit()
{
     if (this.newReg){
          ..save the reg..
     }
     else{
          ..update the reg..
     }
}
```